# python tk.Canvas find_withtagで正常にidが返らない問題

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

tk.Canvasでアイコンイメージとそれに付随するテキストをドラッグで移動させるコードがあります。
しかし、オブジェクトに与えるtagによって、find_withtag()メソッドから正常にidが戻ってきません。よって、move()メソッドも正常に機能しません。

self.drag に操作する対象のtagを格納しております。

```py
tag_list = list()
for weight in self.canvas.find_all():
    t = [ (weight,tags) for tags in self.canvas.gettags(weight) if self.drag_obj in tags]
    tag_list.append(t)

print(tag_list)
print(self.canvas.find_withtag(self.drag_obj) )

self.canvas.move(self.drag_obj,dx,dy)
```

正常時の戻り

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [(3, '000330208100')], [(4, '000330208100'), (4, '000330208100name')]]
(3, 4)
```

異常時の戻り

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [(13, '112233445566')], [(14, '112233445566'), (14, '112233445566name')]]
()
```

リスト上では、'000330208100'、'112233445566'のタグを持つオブジェクトはそれぞれ二つ発見できているのに、find_withtag()では、'112233445566'のときに空で戻ってきてしまいます。

tagとして与える値に何か制約があるのでしょうか？
ご存知の方はご教示をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語サイトのほうで質問したところ、回答をいただけました。
tagsに整数を使用していたため、idなのかTagなのか判別できなかったことが原因でした。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862969/why-does-the-return-value-from-the-tk-canvas-find-withtag-method-become-empty/57863222#57863222